# Adding class to A tag after onclick

Tags: javascript

I have the below code

```
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#" onclick="showNotConfirmedDiv()">
                        <span data-feather="file-text"></span>
                        Not Confirmed<span class="badge updateBadge">1</span>
                        <!-- TODO ONLY SHOW BADGE IF THERE IS A NUMBER!!!!! -->
                    </a>
                </li>
```

I want the add active to the class for the anchor tag when I hit the li.a tag

```
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#" onclick="showNotConfirmedDiv()">
                        <span data-feather="file-text"></span>
                        Not Confirmed<span class="badge updateBadge">1</span>
                        <!-- TODO ONLY SHOW BADGE IF THERE IS A NUMBER!!!!! -->
                    </a>
                </li>
```

This is the JS function I am using..

```
    function showNotConfirmedDiv(e) {
        $('#notConfirmedDiv').show();
        $('#duplicantClientFilesDiv').hide();
        e.classList.add('active');
    }
```

Comment: try  e.target.classList

Comment: You're not passing the argument for the `e` parameter. Change it to `onclick="showNotConfirmedDiv(this)"`

Comment: @AmirHossein_Khakshouri They're not passing the `Event` to the `e` parameter.

Comment: $(".nav-link").removeClass("active"); .... e.classList.add('active');.... i added this to my function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#" onclick="showNotConfirmedDiv(this)">
```

you are not passing `e` parameter in your function `showNotConfirmedDiv` is not receiving any element reference when the function is called and `this` refers to the `current context`,